# OCamllex: regular expression

Tags: ocaml, ocamlyacc, ocamllex

Currently i'm trying to write an interpretter in Ocaml and this is my lexer.mll:

```
{

    open Parser
    exception Eof
}


rule main = parse
      [ ' ' '\t' ]  { main lexbuf } 
    | [ '\n' ]  { EOL } 
    | ['0'-'9']+ as lxm { LINE_NUMBER(int_of_string lxm) }
    | [^\\]*\.(\w+)$  as lxm { FILE_NAME lxm }
    | "get_line"    { GET_LINE }    
    (*| [ ^-?\b([0-9]{1,3}|1[0-9]{3}|20[0-4][0-9]|205[0-5])\b ]     { RANGE }   (* -2055 < RANGE < 2055 *)*)
    | eof   { raise Eof }
```

I'm really confused why ocamllex give me an error at the line { FILE_NAME lxm }. If i put `#load "str.cma"` at the beginning of my lexer, it print out error syntax error on that line.

Why? i'm pretty confused ...

**EDIT**

should be `[ [^\\]*\.(\w+)$ ] as lxm { FILE_NAME lxm }`

But problem is still not solved ...

Answer (score 2):

There are many parts of your regexp that are not recognized:

- `\\`: put it between single quotes to match the "\" character;
- `\.`: just put the dot between single quotes to match a dot,
- `\w`: ocamllex does not seem to know this escaped sequence, you need to define yours,
- `$`: define your line endings.

So first, put this before lexing rules:

```
let w = ['a'-'z' 'A'-'Z' '0'-'9' '_']
let eol = '\n' | "\r\n"
```

Then, change your rule to

```
[^'\\' '\n']*'.'w+eol
```

The matched expression (`lxm`) will contain the line ending sequence (`'\n`' or `"\r\n"`), so you need to remove it.

And be careful when you try to match a string till the end of the line, because the default behavior is to match the longest string, so it can match more than one line at a time if your regexp accept line endings. That's why I forbid the '\n'.

Comment: Is there any way to _not_ match the longest string?